# Macports installer public signing key

Tags: macports

The [MacPorts installation guide](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html) says:

> 1. Download the latest MacPorts-2.3.1-....pkg installer from the [MacPorts download directory](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/). [...]
> 2. Double-click the downloaded package installer to perform the default “easy” install.

In between steps 1 and 2, however, a user may wish to verify the integrity of the downloaded package, using the PGP signature file also found in the Macports download directory.

If SIGNATURE_FILE is the name of the signature file, I get the following result:

```
$ gpg --verify SIGNATURE_FILE
gpg: Signature made Thu 26 Jun 00:37:12 2014 BST using DSA key ID B4AAE6CD
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

Where can I find the public key? [Google doesn't seem to know](https://www.google.com/search?q=macports%20key%20site%3Aguide.macports.com%20-intitle%3AAvailable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key ID is B4AAE6CD, from your command output. You need to search and retrieve the key from a keyserver:

```
gpg --recv-keys B4AAE6CD
```

Then your verify command should work.

Comment: Please check the address of the keyserver, seems to be wrong.

Comment: @Michael, thanks. Using `gpg --recv-keys --keyserver wwwkeys.pgp.net B4AAE6CD` as you suggested produces `gpgkeys: key B4AAE6CD not found on keyserver` `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.` On the plus side, `$ gpg --recv-keys B4AAE6CD` yields a key that can be used to check the integrity of the downloaded file, so I've edited your answer accordingly in order to be able to mark it "accepted".

Comment: (Using that key to verify the signature produces a warning message: `WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!` `There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.` However, this is correct GnuPG behaviour, as explained [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) and [here](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x334.html).)

Comment: It is actually in the original keyserver I posted if you look at the web interface. (all the public ones synchronize with each other) It worked when I tried yesterday. They may be having issues as I can't even connect to it now. Since most gpg installs come with a default keyserver set, it's not strictly necessary to specify one anyways, so thanks for fixing it.